# Access argument from docker build inside script

Tags: bash, docker

So in dockerfile I am running entrypoint:

```
ARG WP_IMAGE=latest
FROM wordpress:$WP_IMAGE

ARG VERSION

RUN curl -o /usr/local/bin/wp https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wp

RUN apt update && apt install -y vim

ADD ./bin/ /
RUN chmod +x /*.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

And I have this script `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh php-fpm || /configure.sh

exec "$@"
```

And there is `configure.sh` script and inside this script I want to access this argument from Dockerfile `VERSION`. 
This is how I build my docker `docker-compose build --build-arg WP_IMAGE=latest --build-arg VERSION=7.0 && docker-compose up -d`.

Comment: What is not working with your build command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ENV` keyword in `Dockerfile` like:

```
ARG VERSION
ENV VERSION=${VERSION}
```

Now the script running in the image can access `VERSION` from the environment.

> The ENV instruction sets the environment variable  to the value
> . The environment variables set using ENV will persist when a
> container is run from the resulting image.